# Runtime.exec throws IllegalMonitorStateException sometimes

Tags: android

We have following code which sometimes throws java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: unlock of unowned monitor

```
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = run.exec(SOME_COMMAND);
```

This code is executed quite early while the application start.

It works fine if I start the application manually. I have never seen any problems with it (for hunders of launches).

However, when it's started as part of testing automation sometimes this code fails with that exception.
Our testing automation does following:

- install our app
- launch it immediately
- execute some tests
- uninstall app
- install app again
- launch it again

Here is the stack track of the crash.

```
  11-14 14:59:26.675: W/dalvikvm(3788): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4120180)
    11-14 14:59:26.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3788): FATAL EXCEPTION: SomeThread
    11-14 14:59:26.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3788): java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: unlock of unowned monitor
    11-14 14:59:26.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3788):     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:229)
    11-14 14:59:26.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3788):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:168)
    11-14 14:59:26.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3788):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:241)
    11-14 14:59:26.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3788):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:184)
    11-14 14:59:26.675: E/AndroidRuntime(3788):     at aaa.SomeThread.run(SomeThread.java:41)
```

I appreciate any ideas or information.

Comment: What version of Android are you using?  I'm aware of a bug that could cause this behavior, but it was fixed in 2.3 (gingerbread).

Comment: can you display more of the catlog result please

Comment: 2fadden: It's happening on 4.0.3. However, I would appreciate if you can point to prior 2.3 bug to look at.